# Understanding Row Constructor Comparison With Multiple Columns

Tags: postgresql, operator

While researching RVC I have found the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#ROW-WISE-COMPARISON) pertaining to the comparison operators `<, >, >=, <=` Although it is clear how:

`select (1,2) < (1,3)` = `true`

Due to already mentioned formula in the documentation `a < c OR (a = c AND b < d)`, it is not so clear as to why:

`select (1,2,null) < (1,3,0)` = `true`

To quote the documentation:

> For the <, <=, > and >= cases, the row elements are compared left-to-right, stopping as soon as an unequal or null pair of elements is found.

and

> For example, ROW(1,2,NULL) < ROW(1,3,0) yields true, not null, because the third pair of elements are not considered.

What is the "third pair" and how is the formula expanded/adapted for more and more columns (for example `select (1,2,3,4,5) < (1,3,0,8,9)`

Also, why does this `select (1,2,0) >= (1,2,null);` return `null` when I would be expecting `true` due to `1>=1` at the beginning.

Comment: The "third pair" is `null, 0`

Comment: Sure, but what is the operation and what is the formula here fully? Because this `select (1,2,0) >= (1,2,null);` returns `null`, is it even using a similar equation to the one for 2 elements? Or is it just doing 1 by 1 comparison? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Well, that was a response to the "*What is the "third pair"*" part of your question

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ah I was hoping for a bit of a more detailed explanation, my bad. Could you provide any deeper explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT (1,2,null) < (1,3,0)
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 < 1
            THEN TRUE
            WHEN 1 > 1
            THEN FALSE
            WHEN 1 = 1
            THEN CASE WHEN 2 < 3
                      THEN TRUE
                      WHEN 2 > 3
                      THEN FALSE
                      WHEN 2 = 3
                      THEN CASE WHEN NULL < 0
                                THEN TRUE
                                WHEN NULL > 0
                                THEN FALSE
                                WHEN NULL = 0
                                THEN FALSE
                           END
                 END
       END;
```

Since 2 is less than 3, the last `CASE` expression (which would return NULL) is not executed.

Comment: Could you also please explain why `select (1,2,0) >= (1,2,null);` returns `null` Because it should return true on the first step of `select case when 1 >= 1 then true` based on what you just wrote.

Comment: That's a different comparison, and it would correspond to a different `CASE` statement. Hint: treat all three cases (`=`, `<` and `>`) differently.